# GWT debug mode is slow on brand new eclipse project

Tags: performance, gwt

I followed the following instructions to start a brand new project in eclipse
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html

Why is debug mode so slow? The default new project has a textbox and a button created in GWT. But they take seconds to show up in debug mode. This is a brand new project why is it going so slow in gwt hosted mode?

Edit: To clarify the documentation clearly says that hosted mode does not convert the Java to javascript.

Comment: It's natural, don't sweat about it - wait till you start having KLOCs in GWT code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT uses a mix of JavaScript and Java (bytecode) in it's Development mode.

See this for more info: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html

> Development mode uses a special engine to run your app as a mix of both Java bytecode and native JavaScript.

Comment: gwt does not translate to javascript in debug mode

Comment: Are you sure?  Can I see your source?  IIRC, it uses a mix of both Java (bytecode) and JavaScript after changes are done and a refresh is made.  The JavaScript is compiled (ie-translated) from your Java that was likely changed.

Comment: Jack, GWT does simple class reloading, that's why sometimes after changes it may be necessary to terminate & restart the application.

Comment: Ah okay, my correction then.  I believed it was more "mixed mode" JS & Java byte code loading.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time to compile your application the first time. It's development mode so you didn't have to compile yourself before deploying, but it has to in order to display it. After the first time, it usually caches most of your class data and then it will be much faster.

Comment: I'd point out that 'the first time' refers to the first page load after dev mode is started, not just the first time you launch dev mode in a new workspace/project.

Comment: It's also true that the first time the page is loaded requires dev mode to compile up a version for that browser, so it's also first-time-load per browser.

Comment: +1 @Colin although I usually close dev mode in between gwt projects

Comment: Dev mode does not compile to javascript.